# Zigbee network sniffing and converting values

Tags: zigbee

I am currently using ember desktop to run zigbee traces on some embeded devices. I have the network keys and device keys so all the data is fine, im just a bit of a noob when it comes to reading the data.

one of the traces i run returns a value for some data and comes back as int24_0: 0x000201 another is the same int24_0: 0x0000D1.

Does anyone know how to read this data of how i can see or even convert this int24 value to a readable value.

thanks

Comment: It depends on the attribute.  You'll need to reference the ZigBee Cluster Library specification for the profile/cluster/attribute ID to see the units of measurement.  Otherwise, it's just a simple hex-to-decimal conversion.  0x201 is 513 and 0xD1 is 209.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on a lot of criteria: the status of your receptor, the Zigbee version (are you 3.0.0 or smaller ?) ..

Here you have a link which summary all Zigbee basics:

[Basics Zigbee](http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Tutorials/Zigbee_tutorial.html)

I also attached the section dedicated to the frame reading (link in the first page):

[Zigbee frame description](http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Tutorials/Zigbee-physical-layer-frame-format.html)